Proving the nested interval property (proof verification)
The text gives the following definition: "a set $\{I_n\mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ of non-empty closed bounded intervals is called nested intervals (clumsy, I know, I am translating from the German here), iff
$ \text {(a) }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$ and
$\text{(b) }\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \quad\left|I_N\right|<\varepsilon$."
The exercise is then to prove that there exists a (unique) $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $ x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n$.
The proof of uniqueness was easy enough, but I am far from confident of my proof of existence, which goes as follows:
Assume for a contradiction that no such $x\in \mathbb R$ exists, so $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} I_n= \emptyset$. (Here comes the implication I am not sure about) It then follows that there exists an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $I_{n+1}\nsubseteq I_n$, because were this not the case, then by the definition of (non-empty) subsets all $I_n$ would share at least one element. This is a contradiction to (a).

No, it's not correct, it doesn't follow like that. Moreover, you didn't use the fact that the intervals are closed, which is necessary. The intersection of open or half open intervals actually might be empty. Hint: write $I_n=[a_n, b_n]$. Show that both sequences $a_n$ an $b_n$ converge to the same limit (they are both monotone and bounded), and show this limit belongs to the intersection.

Your implication is not valid. We could have $I_{n+1}\subset I_n $ but $I_n$ has no common element with $I_{n+2}$.

@hamam_Abdallah , i'm not sure I quite understand your point. Is it not true that if $I_{n+2} \subseteq I_{n+1} \subseteq I_{n}$ then $I_{n+2}\subseteq I_{n}$, i. e. is inclusion not transitive?

As a suggestion, it would be a useful to include an outline of the proof of uniqueness, for completeness.  Thanks.
